# Difference between tf.clip_by_average_norm and tf.clip_by_norm in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm not completely sure of the difference between the two gradients clipping operator `clip_by_average_norm` and `clip_by_norm`. From the documentation, the difference seems to be that `clip_by_norm` uses `l2norm` instead of `l2norm_avg`.

I understand what the L2-norm of a gradient is but what does "average L2-norm" correspond too ?

Documentation reference

- [clip_by_norm](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/train.html#clip_by_norm)
- [clip_by_average_norm](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/train.html#clip_by_average_norm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc are a bit ambiguous, from [test](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/754048a0453a04a761e112ae5d99c149eb9910dd/tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/clip_ops_test.py#L280) and [impl](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/eb56a8af24695bf8258addf28b0c53fbabff72e6/tensorflow/python/ops/clip_ops.py#L268), it seems `avg_norm` is `norm/len(vector)`

```
 def testClipByAverageNormClipped(self):
    # Norm clipping when average clip_norm < 0.83333333
    with self.test_session():
      x = tf.constant([-3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0], shape=[2, 3])
      # Average norm of x = sqrt(3^2 + 4^2) / 6 = 0.83333333
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to look at the test. Indeed, it seems that avg_norm is the norm normalized by the number of element.